# Find if current windows.pathname contains location to li a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to add an `active` class on the link to the current page:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.topmenu li').each(function() {
    var href = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if (href === window.location.pathname) {
      jQuery(this).find('a').addClass('active');

    }
  });
});
```

This works great for matching exactly the pathname, but how can I see if the page I'm on, is a subpage for a link?

When I have a link like this: `<a href="/top-page-1/sub-page-1/">Sub page 1</a>` the code works.

When Im on  `/top-page-1/sub-page-1/`, but when I'm on `/top-page-1/sub-page-1/sub-sub-page-1/`, I don't get an `active` class on the link. Is there any way to this?

Comment: [**String.prototype.indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.topmenu li').each(function() {
    var href = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf(href)>-1) {
      jQuery(this).find('a').addClass('active');

    }
  });
});
```